# Laravel : Cannot access protected property Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm importing xlsx into sql, But while importing I'm getting the following Error:

> ```
> FatalThrowableError in ItemController.php line 41:
> Cannot access protected property Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection::$title
> ```

If anyone face the same problem or know what will be the suggestion,hope you'll help me to find it.

Here is my controller part:

```
    public function importExcel()
        {

            if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
                $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
                })->get();

                if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                     $insert[] = ['title' => $value->title, 'description' => $value->description];
  //Line : 41                    
                    }
                    if(!empty($insert)){
                        DB::table('items')->insert($insert);
                      //  dd('Insert Record successfully.');
                    }
                }
            }
            return back();
        }
```

Route Part:

```
Route::post('/importExcel',[
        'uses'=>'ItemController@importExcel',
        'as'=>'importExcel'
    ]);
```

Here is the importing xlsx file:

[image]

When I dd($data) I saw the following Array:

```
RowCollection {#464 ▼
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#390 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "title" => "Abdul"
        "description" => "This is Zaman"
        0 => null
      ]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#410 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "title" => "Zaman"
        "description" => "This is Abdul"
        0 => null
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is line 41? Also if you try to `dd()` `$value` in your foreach, what is the contents? Perhaps you're trying to access `title` incorrectly. You probably need to use `getTitle()` as it's telling you it's a protected property.

Comment: But I used `title` as public in Model and I edited the Qus you might get idea what's there in line 41

Comment: Please paste the dump of `dd($value)` from your foreach in your question.

Comment: I added , please check once please!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the collection into an array to access each item attributes

```
$data = Excel::load($path)->toArray();

// dd($data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
if (Input::hasFile('import_file')){
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($data, function($reader) {
        // Loop through all rows
        $reader->each(function($row) {
            DB::table('items')->insert([
                'title'       => $row->title,
                'description' => $row->description
            ]);
        });
    });
}
return back();
```

`force_sheets_collection` in `config/excel.php` must be set to `false`.

Comment: I changed the `force_sheets_collection` from false to true but nothing get changed!

Comment: I'm gonna try to reproduce this issue locally.

Comment: Updated answer, adjust accordingly.

Comment: But by the above code I had to load the data form the by default location right?

Comment: Updated my answer to closely reflect your original code.

Comment: Same Error I'm getting Bro ,  `Cannot access protected property Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection::$title`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help more than that. Works fine for me on my end using the exact spreadsheet you are using and settings I've told you to use. You need to start debugging on your own.

Comment: Thanks for helping me till now!
Let's see whether can I help my own!

Comment: Let us know when you figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do another looping like this

```
foreach ($data as $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $insert[] = ['title' => $row->title, 'description' => $row->description];
    }
}
var_dupmp($insert);
```

you should see this result

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Zaman"
    ["description"]=>
    string(13) "This is Zaman"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Abdul"
    ["description"]=>
    string(13) "This is Abdul"
  }
```

Then you can insert this array into database

for more information you can see this answer for issue like this :

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/351